# EJB Find element's parameter ManyToOne

Tags: database, ejb, many-to-one

I have two classes related by ManyToOne, I have the id of "Chantier" and I'd like to find all the Lots which have this chantier's id.

public class Chantier implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String titre_aff;
private String num_aff;
private String ville;
```

public class Lots implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
List<String> numero_lot;
List<String> designation;
@ManyToOne
private Chantier chantier;
```

I tried with this in my LotsREST but it is looking for Lots with this id and not chantier :

```
@GET
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Lots getLotByChantier(@PathParam("id") String id) {
        return faL.find(Long.parseLong(id));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I just created this function to return what i wanted

```
@GET
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Lots> getLotByChantier(@PathParam("id") String id) {
        List<Lots> listLots = faL.findAll();
        for (Lots lot : listLots) {
            if (!lot.getChantier().getId().equals(Long.parseLong(id))) {
                listLots.remove(lot);
            }
        }
        return listLots;
    }
```